# TS exclude keys with dot notation

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can I exclude some keys of an object using dot notation?

I want to write a `ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<T, K>` type to recursively add `string` type to any primitive type property or subproperty, *excluding* any properties at the union of paths specified in `K`, which should be left alone.

For example:

```
type Values = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: string;
      d: number;
    };
    e: string;
  };
  f: number;
  g: number;
  h: {
    i: number;
  }
};

type Result = ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<Values, 'a.b.c' | 'f'>;
/* type Result = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: string; // <-- unchanged
            d: number | string;
        };
        e: string; // <-- (string | string is just string)
    };
    f: number; // unchanged
    g: number | string;
    h: {
        i: number | string;
    };
} */
```

In the above, the `a.b.d`, `a.e`, `a.g`, and `h.i` properties have all been transformed with `| string`, whereas the `a.b.c` and `f` properties have been left alone.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: This is the minimal sample I can provide, to avoid unnecessary complexity I think this sample is good enough and I think can modify the answer for my use-case. my problem is I cannot convert `'a.b.c'` to `'b.c'` an then `'c'` to make it nested. I have tried `EXCLUDE extends ``${infer First}.${infer Rest}`` ? Rest : never` but I'm not sure if it's correct

Comment: I have updated sample code

Comment: Yes and no, Can you explain what does `[P in keyof T as P extends K ? never : P]` do, why do need casting? and can you answer to edited question

Comment: It perfectly works for removing keys, I need some help for `ValueOrEmptyString` and wrapping with generics

Comment: So sorry for typo! Fixed

Comment: You don't really have to explain what your code does. We can figure that out in time. What we don't know is the problem itself and what you want your code to do instead.

Comment: I have a Model and a Form, the model itself is nested and collect data from a Form, some inputs from Form are either null or empty string as their default value for example a age field is number in model but its default value is an empty string

Comment: The would like to create Form from Model

Comment:  I'm sorry but this is not answerable.  Your `Result` type has properties not mentioned at all in `Values`.  Can't you spend some time to make sure that your question is coherent and doesn't have typos?  It's quite disheartening to keep checking this only for it to make less sense over time instead of more sense.

Comment: So sorry, you are right

Comment: Okay uhhhh maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX151N) is what you're looking for?  If so, I'll write up an answer, but... do you mind if *I* [edit] your question to fix the continued problems with it? (e.g., how many definitions of `Values` are there?)  I asked you to *spend some time* making sure the question is coherent and without typos, but it seems you aren't really checking for this.  I'm happy to do the edits myself, if I understand the question.

Comment: Sorry again, I don't know why I made mistake again! can you change ` K extends string` to add a higher level of type checking? so we cannot exclude  `'a.b.z'` which is not exists

Comment: No, I'm exhausted. I can write up my answer and you can add another question to ask about that, or I can completely disengage.  You choose.

Comment: I appreciate your hard working on this. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please, choose one of my two options.

Comment: Please Write up your answer and I'll ask another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach to writing the recursive `ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<T, K>`:

```
type ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<T, K extends string> =
    T extends object ? { [P in keyof T]:
        P extends K ? T[P] : ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<T[P],
            K extends `${Exclude<P, symbol>}.${infer R}` ? R : never
        > } : T | string;
```

One base case is that a primitive (non-`object`) type `T` should become a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of itself and `string`, `T | string`.

Object types `T` are [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).   If the object key `P` is directly a member of `K`, then that's another base case: we leave the object property `T[P]` alone and don't modify it.

Otherwise, we recurse and write `ValueOrStringExcludeNested<T[P], ⋯>`  The possibly tricky part here is figuring out what goes in `⋯`.  We want to take each union member of `K` that starts with `P` and a dot, and convert it to the remainder of the string.  Otherwise we want to drop the union member.  Since operation should *distribute* over unions in `K`,  we want a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  And since we're parsing strings we can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).  Conceptually it's `K extends` ${P}.${infer R} `? R : never`.  There's a wrinkle that `P` is known to extend `string | number | symbol`, and [`symbol`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html#handbook-content) cannot be serialized via template literal type.  So we can write `Exclude<P, symbol>` using [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) instead of `P`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
type Values = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: string;
            d: number;
        };
        e: string;
    };
    f: number;
    g: number;
    h: {
        i: number;
    }
};

type Result = ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<Values, 'a.b.c' | 'f'>;
/* type Result = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: string;
            d: string | number;
        };
        e: string;
    };
    f: number;
    g: string | number;
    h: {
        i: string | number;
    };
} */
```

Looks good.  Primitive types have `string` added to their domain, except for those properties at `a.b.c` and `f`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QPICcDKx0EsB2A5gKIAeAxsgCYQByEAzsBFQNIQgMA8AKgDRRWUCKWb4qDKEzxEAfFAC8AKCiqoPYaIjjJAewBGAKwjlgUAPxQA3lADaABSgEoAaw66AZuoC6ALhVqgY4iYhKCFuoO3lC+sIgoGNgyJBTUdIzMbBzcPFF8AYGF4SHaYQAGACRWZJRINFz2AgwgALb6ugiyAL4AdFUEHhDoUABKXWURIzFQ+BAAbkMFhfJd0xoAPlI4BIQA3EoHoJBxyIyK1ktwsVZLgfrXt0VQ5LHSO-tPhVSx+EhtQx8nl1AUUIK9tkQQVBgUsPD8-voAUtCPD-ugoQALB6fXCoxHopZdJQwpRHaAjRhIBBmBQnBJYCEpWo0ehMFjsThceCnBgCADkcB6+h65D5UE2fI8fNk+wA9AAqKBk0aU6nnG6BK4XT73bWfNQvLbJKGfb5GnbimYIpGfGGfMHmyGEqFwq1oqEox2ES2-d1LLF6oq4r0+60EwIw1by2VKIA)