# In TypeScript limit a generic to list of dot notation keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

This question related to [TS exclude keys with dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77113384/6447123) and I want to make the previous solution more robust.

In the type `type ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<T, K extends string>` the problem is `K extends string` and I would like to restrict `K` to keys and nested keys of `T` in dot notation

I did my best but the result is a total mess

```
type NestedKeyOf<ObjectType extends object> = {
  [Key in keyof ObjectType & (string | number)]: ObjectType[Key] extends object
    ? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<ObjectType[Key]>}`
    : `${Key}`
}[keyof ObjectType & (string | number)]
```

In the above mentioned code, `NestedKeyOf` accept and object and calculate dot notations. but `R` in the previous answer is a Union of dot notation strings.

I also face with `TS2615: Type of property  prototype  circularly references itself in mapped type` error in other tries.

Also note that I would like to change `T` in  `ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<T, K extends string>` to `T extends object`, Maybe `ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<T extends object, K extends NestedKeyOf<T>>`

Comment: This is not something the compiler does well; a deeply recursive type as a constraint of another type is too taxing for some reason.  [This](https://tsplay.dev/m0vMow) is the approach I'd use, (making this a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58434389/2887218)), but it doesn't work well.  This would be much more easily expressed with a function instead of a type.  Not sure how to proceed here.

Comment: What do you think about [This](https://tsplay.dev/mZJe4m) approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type NestedKeyOf<ObjectType extends object> = {
  [Key in keyof ObjectType & (string | number)]: Key extends 'prototype'
    ? never
    : ObjectType[Key] extends object
    ? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<ObjectType[Key]>}`
    : `${Key}`
}[keyof ObjectType & (string | number)]

type ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<T extends object, K extends NestedKeyOf<T>> = _ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<T,K>

type _ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<T, K extends string> =
    T extends object ? { [P in keyof T]:
        P extends K ? T[P] : _ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<T[P],
            K extends `${Exclude<P, symbol>}.${infer R}` ? R : never
        > } : T | string;


type Values = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: string;
            d: number;
        };
        e: string;
    };
    f: number;
    g: number;
    h: {
        i: number;
    }
};

type Result = ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<Values, 'a.b.c' | 'f'>;
/* type Result = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: string;
            d: string | number;
        };
        e: string;
    };
    f: number;
    g: string | number;
    h: {
        i: string | number;
    };
} */


type Oops = ValueOrStringExcludeNestedKeys<Values, 'a.b.c' | 'w'>;
```